# Error: Not able to start debugging on Tizen TV

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, tizen

I'm not being able to debug a Tizen Web Application in a Smart TV. I followed the steps listed [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/web-inspector#tv-device)

When selecting `Debug As > Tizen Web Application` I get the following error message:

> 'Launching Basicapplication' has encountered a problem
> An internal error occurred during: "Launching Basicapplication".
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Launching Basicapplication".
> org.tizen.web.editor.configuration.TizenConfiguratorImpl cannot be cast to org.tizen.web.editor.configuration.IMobileConfigurator

I am using Tizen Studio, and I tried it in both Linux and Windows

Any help on this issue will be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I installed the TV-extension "Web app. development" & "Samsung Certificate Extension" from the Package Manager to fix this.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. I ended up overriding the console functions to write to an on screen <div> instead, and using that to debug. Not the optimal solution, but good enough. If I need to do this again, I'll try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: At least it's a very generic way to debug an webapp :) Cryptic tizen developer environment errors are quite hard deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your signature again, It may be you are building the signed copy of Tizen project and using a different signature.